# Twitter login api with javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to login using the Twitter api's. i read the documentation of the https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing but not getting any fruit full solution. 
Any one have the idea how can i do this thing using the javascript. not with PHP or any thing else.

```
Accept: */*
Authorization: 
        OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsign-in-with-twitter%2F",
              oauth_consumer_key="cChZNFj6T5R0TigYB9yd1w",
              oauth_nonce="ea9ec8429b68d6b77cd5600adbbb0456",
              oauth_signature="F1Li3tvehgcraF8DMJ7OyxO4w9Y%3D",
              oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
              oauth_timestamp="1318467427",
              oauth_version="1.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link and get the twitter library: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries
java script example on git. https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient